# Setting nested object value in session storage

Tags: javascript, session-storage

Hi everyone having a tough time updating a value that I am storing in sessionstorage. I tried a few ways to target the nested objects values with no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Object I am creating in JavaScript**

```
   var projectInfo = {
        project1: {
            name: 'Unique name',
            extraCredit: true
        }
        project2: {
            name: 'Unique name',
            extraCredit: true
        }
    }
```

**How I am persisting to session**

```
sessionStorage.setItem('projectInfo', JSON.stringify(projectInfo));
```

**How do I target the nested project name in project info. For example**

```
sessionStorage.setItem(projectInfo.project1.name, 'Student Fund raiser')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do it like that. You have to retrieve the whole object, parse it, change what you want and then put it back into the storage:

```
var projectInfo = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('projectInfo'));
projectInfo.project1.name = 'Student Fund raiser';
sessionStorage.setItem('projectInfo', JSON.stringify(projectInfo));
```

**Note:** You might as well check if `sessionStorage.getItem` returns something in case the object is not stored yet.

Comment: LOL! Upvoted for beating me by 20 seconds; same as @SteveArcher. This is a good answer and the same as I would have suggested.

Comment: @SteveArcher sorry. Next time, maybe!

Comment: @Anovative Ditto.

Comment: Thank you both for you time , makes sense and worked great.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the value of the nested item while it's stringified (Well, I suppose you theoretically could by parsing the string yourself somehow, but that sounds like a real chore). I think the best approach is to retrieve the string, parse it back to a JS object, set the value, re-stringify it, then store it.

```
var projectString = sessionStorage.getItem('projectInfo')
var projectObject = JSON.parse(projectString)
projectObject.project1.name = 'Student Fund raiser'
sessionStorage.setItem(JSON.stringify(projectObject))
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you get an error, that it cannot be added to null**

Instead ibrahim mahrir's answer:

```
var projectInfo = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('projectInfo'));
projectInfo.project1.name = 'Student Fund raiser';
sessionStorage.setItem('projectInfo', JSON.stringify(projectInfo));
```

Try this:

```
var projectInfo = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('projectInfo'));
projectInfo = projectInfo === null ? {} : projectInfo;
projectInfo.project1.name = 'Student Fund raiser';
sessionStorage.setItem('projectInfo', JSON.stringify(projectInfo));
```